How to share values from sub window to main window without destroying the sub window in tkinter python
I am working on a program which could take input from user in sub window and display a coloured label with width inputted to it. But I can't get the idea to take the input without destroying the sub window
I tried first with functions but after a reasearch I found classes to be useful but still couldn't take the input.
from tkinter import *

rootx = Tk("main")
rootx.title("main")
t = True
class minwindow:
 def __init__(self, window):
  
  
  self.root = Toplevel(window)
  self.root.minsize(100,100)
  self.root.title("mini")
  self.i = IntVar()
  self.A = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.i, width=8)
  self.A.pack(pady = 9)
  self.root.mainloop()

 def show(self):
     self.i = int(self.A.get())
     self.i.set(self.i)
     return self.i
 #def end(self): return  

#minwindow("mini")
m = minwindow(rootx)
w = m.show
a = Label(rootx, bg="green", width= w)
a.pack()
#a.config()
]rootx.mainloop()


***I want to display the label on mainwindow

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Just so you know, you can [edit] your question at any time, so you don't have to add new info in the comments. Unfortunately, this code won't run as-is due to a typo on the last line: ]rootx.mainloop(), and your indentation has some issues. Please take a look at [ask], and see here for info on how to provide a [mre].

If I got it right, something like this would do, the second window changes a Label on the main window.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Toplevel Window')

        ttk.Button(self, text='Close', command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Show App Msg", command=self.parent.msg).pack()
    
   
  

class App(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.title('Main Window')

        # place a button on the root window
        ttk.Button(self, text='Open a window', command = self.open_window).pack(expand=True)
        self.label_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.label_var).pack()
        
    def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self)
        window.grab_set()

    def msg(self):
        self.label_var.set('Hello World')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

I made a adaptation from the this code

You should run .mainloop() only once, so remove self.root.mainloop() inside minwindow.__init__().
For your case, suggest to pass label a to minwindow and update its width after inputting value in the entry widget:
from tkinter import *

rootx = Tk("main")
rootx.title("main")
rootx.minsize(300, 100)

class minwindow:
    def __init__(self, window, label):
        self.label = label  # save the passed label

        self.root = Toplevel(window)
        self.root.minsize(100, 100)
        self.root.title("mini")

        self.i = IntVar()
        self.A = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.i, width=8)
        self.A.pack(pady=9)

        # update label width whenever "Enter" key is pressed in the entry box
        self.A.bind("<Return>", self.update_label)

    def update_label(self, event):
        try:
            w = self.i.get()
            self.label.config(width=w)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex.__class__, ex)

a = Label(rootx, bg="green")
a.pack()

m = minwindow(rootx, a)  # pass a to minwindow

rootx.mainloop()


SIR,  WHEN I REMOVED THE MAINLOOP IN TOPLEVEL AND DID IN A SIMILAR MANNER, I GOT IT. THANK YOU
